# Can't use the import os command in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I'm using the python compiler in java and I tried `import os` .

My problem is when I couldn't input it to continue the next line while it just sent back this message `os is not yet implemented in skulpt on line 1` .

I already tried with another app and still get a same result. I tried to search Google but no result. I read in learning web and it's never seem the existence of this error.

What is skulpt? Please help me

Comment: You need to be more clear with the issue. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Skulpt is essentially a Python interpreter implemented in Javascript, not Java. Is that what you meant? Are you using `ipython`? Why is this questioned tagged with that? If you are using Skulpt, then clearly the `os` module is not implemented yet.

Comment: You would be well advised to read [help] and especially [mcve]

Comment: but i just begin with python not long time,i don't know these applications are use skulpt or what,i even didn't know the existence of skult.But i use python because it ability and high comfortable while i don't know it but you.i thought i just do anything like they do with python.<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga">juanpa-arrivillaga</a>

Comment: *Skulpt* is a Python interpreter written in Javascript. This means it can run in your browser without installing anything, but it can't do everything that regular Python (installed on your computer or on a server) can do. If you just want to try without installing anything, I'd recommend something like [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), which will run your code on their servers. If you're ready to dive in, you can [download Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: It means the what it says, what your attempting to import, isn't yet implemented into Skulpt.  You don't know what Skilpt is?

Answer (score 2):

To find which standard modules the most recent version of `skulpt` supports and which it doesn't, get a copy of the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt.git
```

And, look through the `src/lib` directory.  Every successfully implemented module will be [a directory in `/src/lib`](https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/issues/60).  `os` is not one of those directories. **Module `os` is not implemented in `skulpt`.**